Use f-string instead of format call
The server I'm posting ym data to doesn't seem to support format call so I get the folowing error.
Use f-string instead of 'format' call for the functions below.
def write_xlsx_response(self, queryset):
        response = HttpResponse(
            content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        )
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="{}.xlsx"'.format(
            self.get_filename()
        )
        export_xlsx_assessment(queryset, response)
        return response

def write_csv_response(self, queryset):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/CSV")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="{}.csv"'.format(
            self.get_filename()
        )
        export_csv_assessment(queryset, response)

        return response

Please how can I convert this to f-string.
Thanks

Using an f-string won't work either, if the server is so hopelessly outdated that .format isn't even supported. (That means Python 2.x, since even Python 3.0 has .format)

Please post full error traceback.

the syntax for f-strings and .format is basically the same, you just move the parameters to inside the string and add an f to the front
f'attachment; filename="{self.get_filename()}.csv"'

